# How to call a url and get response from it in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

I want to call a url with passing some parameter and i want to process the response coming from that url in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for AJAX.

There are a number of exceptional libraries out there that take most of the work off your hands, I like jQuery, but have a used a few others (Prototype, Dojo etc).

From the jQuery docs:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/